# Accessing images without logging in

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP .Net site which requires users to log in i.e. http://www.example.com.

They login and upload images which are stored under the images folder, under the root of the site i.e.

```
MySite
  App_Code
  App_Data
  Images
    Employee Images
      Employee1.jpg
      Employee2.jpg
      Employee3.jpg
    Country Logos
      Country1.jpg
      Country2.jpg
      Country3.jpg
....
```

I now have a second project **completely separate** from the above. I need to display the images from the above location but if i use http://www.example.com/images/ i am forced to log in.

How could i access the images without logging in?

Comment: You have to change the permission of the Network folder to allow everybody read access and only selected groups/users full access.

Comment: Ok i can do that and set it to "Everyone" for testing, even then if i navigate to http://www.example.com/images/ i cant get to the images, or are you saying i should try and access the images by the folder path i.e. C:\MySite\Images....?

Comment: A network folder should work if the access is set properly.  All folders may not be set to Everyone.

Comment: So im using an Image but if i set the image location to one i know exists, it doesnt display the image?

Comment: What are you using to display?   Can you display with other tools?  Do the file sizes match the original file size?

Comment: At present I'm using an ASP image control. I could try with other tools? File sizes are different but I can adjust them at a later time once I have the image displaying

Comment: Is the second project a separate website? If so, if you add a "Virtual Directory" in the second website and point its physical path to the "Images" directory of the example.com website then you'll be able to use the images.

Comment: Why would copy file sizes be different.  The files may be corrupt if the sizes do not match exactly except if it is a few bytes because the Directory Browser is round the numbers.  I want to see if the files actually opened to make sure there weren't corrupted during the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write controller function in order to access files in the protected directory. Then control access to that controller.

Comment: Store images in the App_Data folder

Comment: Files in the App_Data directory would normally not be served by IIS as request filtering has it listed under "Hidden Segments".